# Updating existing products' info from CJ datafeed updates

Tags: affiliate, datafeed, commission-junction

I know variations on this question have been asked, but I think this is specific enough to merit a new question.

When I receive an updated data feed from Commission Junction I dump it all into a database. Then those products become searchable and selectable for use on our site. However, since all of the data used seems to be fluid, how can I update the products I have saved on the site with the new information? How can I match new info to existing products?

I'm hoping that someone has been doing this long enough to be able to say certain fields *rarely* change and can generally be relied upon, etc. etc.

Thank you!

Comment: As a CJ advertiser I can tell you that SKU numbers never change.

Comment: Thanks, I'll start with that.